# How to add a default constraint on existing column which applies to existing data in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have following table with data

```
create table emp_status(
    empno number,
    status varchar2(10)
    );
insert into emp_status values(100,null);
insert into emp_status values(200,null);
alter table emp_status modify status default 'Active';

select * from emp_status;
    empno status
    100   null
    200   null
```

I don't see the default values like 'Active' for above records.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting values explicitly saying to insert `NULL` into the column `status`; this way, you are not using the default value.
If you need a column with a default value and want to avoid null values, you can add a `NOT NULL` constraint to your column:

```
create table emp_status(
    empno number,
    status varchar2(10)
    );

alter table emp_status modify status default 'Active' NOT NULL;
```

Now you can insert your values without specicying the value for `status`:

```
SQL> insert into emp_status(empNo) values(100);

1 row created.

SQL> select status from emp_status;

STATUS
----------
Active
```

And you can NOT insert rows with `NULL` `status`

```
SQL> insert into emp_status(empNo, status) values(200, null);
insert into emp_status(empNo, status) values(200, null)
                                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ALEK"."EMP_STATUS"."STATUS")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change default value to 'Active'
Oracle will assign this value to new rows you are trying to insert, when this column a not specified, e.g.:

```
insert into emp_status (empno) values(100);
```

To update previously inserted rows you can use update statement:

```
update emp_status set  status = 'Active' where status is null;
```